# reading nested xml file

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<SalesReps>
  <SalesRep>
    <repname> Bob</repname>
      <repid>100</repid>
      <customers>
        <customer>
          <custname>ABC Company</custname>
          <custno>51233</custno>
        </customer>
        <customer>
          <custname>XYZ Inc.</custname>
          <custno>29943</custno>
        </customer>
      </customers>
    </SalesRep>
  <SalesRep>
    <repname>Sue</repname>
      <repid>43</repid>
      <customers>
        <customer>
          <custname>Petes Tire Co</custname>
          <custno>49999</custno>
        </customer>
        <customer>
          <custname>Suzy's Sewing</custname>
          <custno>81234</custno>
        </customer>
      </customers>
    </SalesRep>
</SalesReps>
```

I'm trying to read it in with the following code:

```
Dim salesreps = From reps In xe.Descendants("SalesReps") Select reps
Dim el = (From rep In salesreps _
Select New With {.repname = rep.<repname>, _
                 .repid = rep.<repid>,
                 .customers = (From custs In rep.<Customers> _
                   Select New With { _
                   .customer = ( _
                       From cust In custs.<customer> _
                           Select New With {
                           .custname = cust.<custname>.Value, _
                           .custno = cust.<custno>.Value} _
                       )} _
                  ) _
              } _
)
```

I can get the repname and repid, but am not getting the customer list with custname and custno.  What am I doing wrong?

Thx

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with LINQ to directly answer your question, but I would like to ask you if you have or would consider using XML deserialization to read this XML document?  LINQ is a convenient way to query certain parts of a document, but if you're just reading in the whole thing, it seems like a lot of work, complexity, and fragility.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SteveDog.  You can use the Xml Serializer to do this.  Here is some sample code:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot("SalesReps")> _
Public Class SalesReps
    Inherits List(Of SalesRep)
End Class

Public Class SalesRep
    Public Property RepName As String
    Public Property RepId As Integer

    <XmlArray("Customers"), XmlArrayItem("Customer")> _
    Public Property Customers As List(Of Customer)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Customers = New List(Of Customer)()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Property CustName As String
    Public Property CustNo As String
End Class

Module Module1                                                                                    
    Sub Main()                                                                                    

        Dim Reps As New SalesReps()                                                               

        Dim rep As New SalesRep With {.RepId = 100, .RepName = "Bob"}                             
        rep.Customers.Add(New Customer With {.CustName = "ABC Company", .CustNo = "51233"})       
        rep.Customers.Add(New Customer With {.CustName = "XYZ Inc.", .CustNo = "29943"})          
        Reps.Add(rep)                                                                             

        rep = New SalesRep With {.RepId = 43, .RepName = "Sue"}                                   
        rep.Customers.Add(New Customer With {.CustName = "Petes Tire Company", .CustNo = "49999"})
        rep.Customers.Add(New Customer With {.CustName = "Suzy's Sewing", .CustNo = "81243"})     
        Reps.Add(rep)                                                                             

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()                                                             

        Dim xSer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(SalesReps))                                         
        Using wrt As New StringWriter(sb)                                                         
            xSer.Serialize(wrt, Reps)                                                             
        End Using                                                                                 

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())                                                          

        Dim NewReps As SalesReps = Nothing                                                        
        Using rdr As New StringReader(sb.ToString())                                              
            NewReps = xSer.Deserialize(rdr)                                                       
        End Using                                                                                 

        If NewReps IsNot Nothing Then                                                             
            Dim firstRep = NewReps.First()                                                        

            Console.WriteLine(firstRep.RepName)                                                   
            For Each cust As Customer In firstRep.Customers                                       
                Console.WriteLine("   {0}", cust.CustName)                                        
            Next                                                                                  
        End If                                                                                    

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...")                                               
        Console.ReadLine()                                                                        
    End Sub                                                                                       
End Module
```

Which produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SalesReps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SalesRep>
    <RepName>Bob</RepName>
    <RepId>100</RepId>
    <Customers>
      <Customer>
        <CustName>ABC Company</CustName>
        <CustNo>51233</CustNo>
      </Customer>
      <Customer>
        <CustName>XYZ Inc.</CustName>
        <CustNo>29943</CustNo>
      </Customer>
    </Customers>
  </SalesRep>
  <SalesRep>
    <RepName>Sue</RepName>
    <RepId>43</RepId>
    <Customers>
      <Customer>
        <CustName>Petes Tire Company</CustName>
        <CustNo>49999</CustNo>
      </Customer>
      <Customer>
        <CustName>Suzy's Sewing</CustName>
        <CustNo>81243</CustNo>
      </Customer>
    </Customers>
  </SalesRep>
</SalesReps>
Bob
   ABC Company
   XYZ Inc.
Press ENTER to exit...
```

Comment: That's great for writing, but the question was about how to read an XML file, which this doesn't help to accomplish.

Comment: @Taegost - Firstly, you are replying to a post that is over two years old!  Secondly, my code shows how to deserialize the xml also.

Comment: True, sorry I didn't word my comment very well, what I meant to say was that this is a somewhat convoluted answer which would be confusing to people that are trying to address similar questions.